# Autocomplete - Add left icon to text field which is in an autocomplete component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have an autocomplete component which render tags
[Autocomplete with tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVPvI.png)

and I want to render a left icon
but only the right icon works correctly

**Current Behavior**

when adding a left icon it shows the icon but doesn't let rendering the tags inside the textField

**Expected Behavior**

when adding a left icon it should let rendering the tags inside the textField

**Step to reproduce:**

**works** when adding the end icon:

```
 const renderInput = (params: Params): ReactNode => {
        if (leftIcon) params.InputProps.endAdornment = <InputAdornment position="end">{leftIcon}</InputAdornment>;

        return <TextField {...params} variant="outlined" placeholder={getPlaceHolderText()} />;
    };
```

**doesn't work** when adding the start icon

```
const renderInput = (params: Params): ReactNode => {
        if (leftIcon) params.InputProps.startAdornment = <InputAdornment position="start">{leftIcon}</InputAdornment>;

        return <TextField {...params} variant="outlined" placeholder={getPlaceHolderText()} />;
    };
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is because the tags are rendered inside the `startAdornment`,
when you set the `startAdornment` to be equal to the icon
it deletes the tags.

so you can set the `startAdornment` with an empty `htmlTag` (`<>`) and render your relevant component inside and also the previous content of the `startAdornment`

ex: It works to me

```
const renderInput = (params: Params): ReactNode => {
        if (leftIcon)
            params.InputProps.startAdornment = (
                <>
                    <InputAdornment position="start">{leftIcon}</InputAdornment>
                    {params.InputProps.startAdornment}
                </>
            );

        return <TextField {...params} variant="outlined" placeholder={getPlaceHolderText()} />;
    };
```